# Eclipse java editor marking generated (Groovy) methods as undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

Eclipse 2020-03 is indicating that generated Groovy methods do not exist when they are referenced inside a Java class.

I created a new Groovy project in Eclipse 2020-03 to illustrate this.  I did not modify the project in any way from the defaults.

My Groovy object:

```
class MyPogo {
    String id
}
```

Access it in Groovy script

```
MyPogo g = new MyPogo()
g.setId("foo")
println(g.getId())
```

Access it in Java:

```
public class DemoAccessor {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        MyPogo p = new MyPogo();
        p.setId("foo");
        System.out.println(p.getId());
    }
}
```

In the Java perspective, both setId and getId are underlined in red with the gutter message reading

```
"The method setId(String) is undefined for the type MyPogo"
```

A similar message is given for getId(String).

When run as a Java Application inside Eclipse, both the groovy script and DemoAccessor print 'foo' to the console.

Why doesn't Eclipse recognize these generated methods?  Do I need to add a -javaagent:... to eclipse.ini?  Is there a Preference that I need to adjust?

.project contains

```
...
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
...
```

.classpath contains

```
...
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="GROOVY_SUPPORT"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="GROOVY_DSL_SUPPORT"/>
...
```

Problems view
[image: Problems view]

Package Explorer
[image: Package Explorer]

Error View
[image]

Comment: I think you should log an issue https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/

Comment: This should work. I'm not sure if Groovy is active in your workspace or project. Can you include a screenshot of your Package Explorer and Error Log views in addition to the sources?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the requested screenshots.

Comment: If you clear your Error Log and restart Eclipse, do any new errors appear when you open the two sources?

Comment: I cleared the Error Log, restarted Eclipse, there were a bunch of errors in the Log again so I cleared it and opened the project - no new errors show up.  I will zip up my project and attach it here if I can.

Comment: When you restart and errors are shown, what are the errors?

Comment: Are you running Eclipse with Java greater than 8?  Many of the errors are for missing javax.annotation.PostConstruct.  This was included with Java SE, but has moved to Java EE.  There may be a missing package import in the recommenders bundle(s).  May be a red herring, but worth looking into.

Comment: There are also errors for "$5" in a groovy source.  Where are these coming from?  They are not part of the included project.

Comment: Unfortunately I am away from the system where I was experiencing this and won't be back for a week; I will see if I can continue to diagnose this on another system.  The question about the "$5" is a good one; I have no idea where that would be.  I cannot remember for certain but I think I am running Java 14.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, even in the default package.

[image]

If you look under Help > About Eclipse ... > Installation Details > Plug-ins, what version is showing for Java Development Tools Core (org.eclipse.jdt.core)?  This is the critical bundle that GDT patches to wedge its compiler into the JDT.

Comment: The version of org.eclipse.jdt.core is 3.21.0.v202005062338-e2003

Comment: Can you zip your project and share it?  What you have shown looks correct.  It is hard to find the missing piece one question at a time.

Comment: link to error log and project archive: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s57tnmce8c0r3ik/AABp8npT7HGxSJc4QdOnQI6ba?dl=0

Comment: Project works as-is when I import it.  I think one of your Eclipse features is getting in the way.  There are a number of errors in the log you included.  I'd work to eliminate them by disabling features or updating plug-ins or ...

Comment: All of my plugins are up to date.I imported the project into  a clean install of Eclipse 2020-03 with org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.21.0.v202005062338-e2003.  The error indicators are not present so I have to assume you're correct about one of the features getting in the way.  Unfortunately I am away from the office for a week so I won't be able to figure out which feature is causing this problem for a while.  I will come back here with an update when i figure out which plugin(s) are causing trouble.

Comment: BTW, how do I disable plugins and features?  I've look around but so far nothing in the UI jumps out at me.

Comment: I tried removing some plugins but nothing seemed to fix the issue.  I ended up re-installing Eclipse and after adding the few plugins that I need this issue no longer appears.